# Invert Slider Control top MFC C++

Tags: c++, mfc, slider

I have a MFC project in which I use a Slider Control. When I set this slider to vertical, the upside is the lowest and the downside is the heigest. How can I invert this, so that the highest value is closest to the top of the screen and the lowest value is closesd to the bottom of the screen?

Comment: When you create it, this looks hopeful: *TBS_DOWNISLEFT
By default, the trackbar control uses down equal to right and up equal to left. Use the TBS_DOWNISLEFT style to reverse the default, making down equal left and up equal right.*

Comment: I changed CONTROL         "",SC_kinectAngle,"msctls_trackbar32",TBS_VERT | TBS_BOTH | TBS_NOTICKS | WS_TABSTOP,114,22,17,138
To:
CONTROL         "",SC_kinectAngle,"msctls_trackbar32",TBS_VERT | TBS_BOTH | TBS_NOTICKS | TBS_DOWNISLEFT | WS_TABSTOP,114,22,17,138
But nothing happend!

Answer (score 0):

if you choose to set range from 0, 100  - then you have to position slider at position 100, and every time slider is moved, you must take 100 minus the slider position